# How can I make a war file from java code without command line?

Tags: java, build, automation

I have a problem. I manage many websites and my colleagues doesn't like our build and deploy process. This process uses many many shell scripts, docker commands etc. So they have to create lot of non-java code.

My goal is to create a solution which allowes them to write java code define build and deploy processes. I hope this would motivate them more to participate in implementing build and deploy process.

Is there any existing solution in this topic?

Comment: You can use jenkins to configure your build and deploy procedure. But you might need to specify the docker commands and shell scripts in the jenkins configuration file. Build and deploy will happen based on the scheduler or even can be configured in such a way that if you merge your code to git hub. Why you want to do it from a Java Code?

Comment: There are many, many ways to automate build and deploy processes. SO isn't the place to get them enumerated, though.